# Optimizing a positive definite quadratic form with inequality constraints.

Tags: optimization

I have a positive definite, multidimensional quadratic form: $(x-x_o)^t M (x-x_o)$, where the "${}^t$" indicates transpose and $M$ is a positive definite matrix (in fact, it is a multidimensional guassian). So I know there is a single global maximum (at $(x_o,y_o)$). Problem is that I need the maximum subject to the constraint that all coordinates of the extremum must be non-negative. I know the desired maximum must have at least one zero coordinate (i.e. it is in the enclosing boundary). Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: I am confused. If $M$ is *positive* definite, then the quadratic form is unbounded from above and has no maximum. It does has a global minimum at $x_o$. As for your question: Are you searching for the maximizer of $(x-x_o)^t M (x-x_o)$ subject to $x\ge 0$?

Comment: I'm sorry. You are right, It is the minimum I'm searching for, subject to x non-negative for each coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

According to comments, the answer is about minimizing a strictly convex quadratic form:

- If you just need a software package to solve it, most packages do that, like Matlab. Just look for quadratic programming.
- If you need a method to compute a solution, there is for example the projected gradient or interior point method.
- If you need a theoretical results, you should consider the [Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).